# PHP - Deserialize multiple serialized object from a text file

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

I'm storing objects of a class on a file like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $merenda = new Merenda($_POST["name"], $_POST["numberOfDisp"], $_POST["cost"]);
    $merenda = serialize($merenda);
    file_put_contents('merende.txt', $merenda, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

So I'm trying to fetch all objects from another page like this:

```
    $serialized = file_get_contents( "merende.txt" );
    $unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );
```

*the content of the serialized file is all in one line, with no break rows*

The problem is that the unserialize() function doesn't return an array of objects but only an object passing it a serialized string. **I'm looking for a way that I can get an object array from a serialized object file. How could I do it?**

Comment: Could your provide data input data ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm sorry man, what do you mean? are u talking about the content of file?

Comment: You can't just FILE_APPEND multiple serialized objects into one file and then expect unserialize to give you an array of them back. You would have to build an array first, and then serialize the array.

Comment: Does the object do anything special to the values passed to the constructor? I.e., does the file contain anything besides those three raw POST values? If not, just write your values to a CSV with fputcsv() and then read it back by using fgetcsv() to process a line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save serialized object in a new row in the file.

Then when you need to unserialize objects you need to read the file row by row and unserialize each row.

For example:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $merenda = new Merenda($_POST["name"], $_POST["numberOfDisp"], $_POST["cost"]);
    $merenda = serialize($merenda) . PHP_EOL;;
    file_put_contents('merende.txt', $merenda, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

```
<?php

$fileContent = file_get_contents( "merende.txt" );
$objects = [];
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $fileContent) as $row) {
    $object = unserialize($row);

    if ($object) {
        $objects[] = $object;
    }
}
```

It is just example to understand the idea, it can be implemented more beautifully.

Comment: `file` reads lines into an array, try `$unserialized = array_map('unserialize', file('merende.txt'));`

Comment: If you serialize a string containing a line break, this will break. Serialize output should be considered a binary string, which means there is functionally _no_ safe separator.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, it is just example to show the idea, as I said it is not a complete solution.

Comment: @Sammitch, yes, I agree with you, we need to additionally handle such cases. But it is just idea, we cannot know which type of data will be used and cannot provide full solution for all possibility cases here.

Comment: Knowing the breadth of input data is irrelevant when we know the constraints of the output format.

Comment: @Sammitch FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES

Comment: @AbraCadaver not relevant.